# Filter Taxonomy Widget Options by Entity Reference

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, entities

I have two content types, Lesson Plan and Course. When creating a Lesson Plan, users select a Course (Entity Reference). Later, they choose course goals (Term Reference) that the Lesson Plan meets. I'd like to filter the list of course goals by the earlier selection, Course. Each Course has a number of course goals (Term Reference).

Is this possible? I've tried using Term / Entity Reference Views, but can't figure out how to pass the selected Course as an argument and have the term list update (AJAX).

Answer (score 0):

It is possible and can be implemented using [Simple Hierarchical Select](https://www.drupal.org/project/shs). From the modules page-

> Simple hierarchical select defines a new form widget for taxonomy fields to select a term by "browsing" through the vocabularies hierarchy.

Expose the view filters (course and course goals) in your case after you set the field type to simple hierarchical select. This [guide](https://www.webwash.net/using-simple-hierarchical-select-module-in-drupal-7/) might be helpful.